# Difference between unlocked iPhone and carrier iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to buy an iPhone 5S and I think it's not directly from apple but it's from a carrier. what I want to know is the difference between the official version and this version, besides the fact that carriers' phones may only use one carrier SIM... I'm asking about software "or" hardware differences

Comment: This can change country to country & provider to provider, so check with them before you buy.

Answer (score 1):

An unlocked phone is sometimes called a SIM-Free or contract-free phone. Unlocking means that you can use your phone with a different carrier. Hope this will help you.